# CSV file records displayed on same line

Tags: excel, csv

I am facing a strange issue where a .csv file when opened in excel displays some records on the same line. This seems to be related to the length of the record when its too big.

But when I open the same file in notepad++, the records are displayed in separate lines and they are delimited by "LF" correctly. So not sure why excel would display these records on the same line.

An example  below. The text "SABELDANS" of the second record below seems to start after 858794 (at the end of first record when displayed in excel).

```
"SABELDANS","OT","MOD","25274158","C","1","This work is not in counter claim","Matching work(s)","N","","","","","","","","","","","Y","34272|231239|329582|333419|762995|1357547|1464429|1572510|1785885|1844725|1932081|2031744|2396019|2775180|4328892|4381870|5246214|6208617|6499832|6505945|6532363|6580666|6614642|6633451|6638457|6646089|6715365|6865558|6969415|6977883|7006247|7010024|7140517|7149974|7202837|7263397|7311456|7483095|7612335|7677011|7814632|7838530|8126796|8458299|8479322|8567215|8586738|858794
"SABELDANS","OT","MOD","25463643","C","1","This work is not in counter claim","Matching work(s)","N","","","","","","","","","","","Y","34272|231239|329582|333419|762995|1357547|1464429|1572510|1785885|1844725|1932081|2031744|2396019|2775180|4328892|4381870|5246214|6499832|6505945|6532363|6580666|6614642|6633451|6638457|6646089|6715365|6865558|6969415|6977883|7006247|7010024|7140517|7202837|7263397|7311456|7483095|7612335|7677011|7814632|7838530|8126796|8458299|8479322|8567215|8586738|8587942|8593619|860017
```

[image]

Comment: can we get an example?

Comment: It is always best practice to import CSV files using either the legacy wizard or power query. At that time, you can easily define a separator, column types and encoding.

Answer (score 1):

In notepad++, go to the View > Show Symbol menu and select Show End of Line. Do you see LF ? Or CR LF maybe ?
You could check the file encoding also, could there be a problem there ?

Comment: Yup, already tried that.. That's how I found out that the lines were correctly delimited by "LF"

Comment: Thanks for adding an exemple. You're missing a guillemet at the end of the first line, i'm guessing this could be it. Try adding it and let us know if it helps ;) Also at the end of the second line